# How can I use the Segmented Control to show all the categories from my plist?

Tags: ios, controls, tableview, plist

Okay so I created a plist that has 7 categories All, A, B, C, D, E, F. Each category has a list of items in them. Now I am trying to use the segmented control so that if user clicks on A it shows all the items that are listed in the A category on the tableview.

So far my code look like this to get the listed items:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Setup the Search Controller
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Summons"
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
definesPresentationContext = true

 // Setup the Scope Bar
 searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
 searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

 // Setup the search footer
 tableView.tableFooterView = searchFooter

 if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
 let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
 detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
 }
  //Load Plist File
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Summonses", ofType: "plist")
    let dics = NSArray.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:path!)) as! [NSDictionary]


    self.originalData = dics.map{Summonses.init(category: $0["category"] as! String, price: $0["price"] as! String, description: $0["description"] as! String, accusatory: $0["accusatory"] as! String, name: $0["name"] as! String, info: $0["info"] as! String)}

    self.filteredData = self.originalData


 }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isFiltering() {

            searchFooter.setIsFilteringToShow(filteredItemCount: filteredData.count, of: originalData.count)
        return filteredData.count
        }
        switch (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex){
       case 0:
          return filteredData.count
       case 1:
           //Not exactly sure what to put in this section to count for the items in category A
           //return filteredData.category["A"].count <--- something like that
        default:
           break
       }
```

like on my scope search bar it does it but I cant seem to get it to work with the segmented control. The category for the summonses are contained with strings "All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" and I just want the items to show up on table view if User hits A all the items in category A shows up. Made a comment on my code on the top I am not sure what sort of code to put in that spot to count all the items that has A in their category.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to load all categories using segment index. Change cellForRowAt indexPath according to your requirement .

```
struct Summonses {
    var category:String
    var price:String
    var description:String
    var accusatory:String
    var name :String
    var info:String
}
class CategoryViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating ,UISearchBarDelegate{


    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    let categories = ["All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    var originalData = [Summonses]()
    var filteredData = [Summonses]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Summons"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        }
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // Setup the Scope Bar
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = categories
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Summonses", ofType: "plist")
        let dics = NSArray.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:path!)) as! [NSDictionary]

        self.originalData = dics.map{Summonses.init(category: $0["category"] as! String, price: String(describing: $0["price"]), description: $0["description"] as! String, accusatory: $0["accusatory"] as! String, name: $0["name"] as! String, info: $0["info"] as! String)}

        self.filteredData = self.originalData


    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
    {
        print(selectedScope)
        if selectedScope != 0 {
            filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            let array = self.originalData.filter{$0.category.contains(categories[selectedScope])}
            filteredData = array
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else{
            filteredData = originalData
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         self.filteredData = self.originalData
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if !((searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty)!){
            filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            let array = self.originalData.filter{$0.category.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)}
            filteredData = array
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if self.searchController.isActive {
            return self.filteredData.count
        }else{
            return self.originalData.count
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : UITableViewCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let objSummonses : Summonses = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(objSummonses.category) -> \(objSummonses.name)"
        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: ok so i looked into the code at home and I didnt really see you implementing the selectedsegmentindex anywhere in the code. It just seemed like you just modified my scopebar.

Comment: selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange this method will give the index for segment control in search bar read doc for more details